# Replace all spaces with only one space and all the new lines with only one new line

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to replace all the new lines and spaces in a string with one new line and one space exactly, currently i am using:

```
data=' '.join(data.split())
```

which is replacing all every thing (new lines as well as spaces) with one space.

I have used the following as well:

```
data = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n\n', data)
data = data.replace('\n', '')
data = re.sub(r"''", "'\n'", data)
data = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', data)
re.sub(' +', ' ', data)
```

but haven't got what i wanted.

Part of sample string:

```
Sonderforschungsbereiche
                              laufende Projekte
                                                     

                                         
                                        SFB 806: Unser Weg nach Europa: Kultur-Umwelt Interaktion und menschliche Mobilität im Späten Quartär


                                                                                            (Sprecher
                                                                                                                                                         
                                                         Richter, Jürgen

                                                                                                )


                                             



                                                     

                                         
                                        SFB 917: Resistiv schaltende Chalkogenide für zukünftige Elektronikanwendungen: Struktur,
Kinetik und Bauelementskalierung  "Nanoswitches"


                                                                                            (Sprecher
                                                                                                                                                         
                                                         Wuttig, Matthias

                                                                                                )
```

Expected Result:

```
Sonderforschungsbereiche
laufende Projekte   
SFB 806: Unser Weg nach Europa: Kultur-Umwelt Interaktion und menschliche Mobilität im Späten
Quartär   (Sprecher Richter, Jürgen )   
SFB 917: Resistiv schaltende Chalkogenide für zukünftige
Elektronikanwendungen: Struktur, Kinetik und "Nanoswitches"
(Sprecher Wuttig, Matthias )
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202467/discussion-on-question-by-jawad-ahmad-khan-replace-all-spaces-with-only-one-spac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace all multiple linebreaks followed by optional white spaces by a single linebreak and all multiple white spaces by a single white space:

- Find : `(\n)+\s*|(\s)+`
- Replace: `\1\2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3gfrbF/1)